# react-native link command not found . How can I solve this trouble?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-ios

Here are the versions that I am using. 
expo 18.0.4,
native-base: 2.2.1,
react 16.0.0-alpha.12,
react-native https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-18.0.1.tar.gz,
react-navigation: 1.0.0-beta.11
After installing react-native library I typed `react-native link` as it was needed by their documentation while it shows command not found.

Comment: Try using RNPM: https://github.com/rnpm/rnpm

Comment: Thanks for replying will it work with EXPO?

Comment: It should work with any react-native based project..

Comment: Thanks a lot its solved.